# Generating a file in one Gradle task to be operated on by another Gradle task

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am working with Gradle for the first time on a project, having come from Ant on my last project.  So far I like what I have been seeing, though I'm trying to figure out how to do some things that have kind of been throwing me for a loop.  I am wondering what is the right pattern to use in the following situation.

I have a series of files on which I need to perform a number of operations.  Each task operates on the newly generated output files of the task that came before it.  I will try to contrive an example to demonstrate my question, since my project is somewhat more complicated and internal.

### Stage One

First, let's say I have a task that must write out 100 separate text files with a random number in each.  The name of the file doesn't matter, and let's say they all will live under parentFolder.

Example:

```
parentFolder
|
|-file1
|-file2
...
|-file100
```

I would think my initial take would be to do this in a loop inside the doLast (shortcutted with <<) closure of a custom task -- something like this:

```
task generateNumberFiles << {
  File parentFolder = mkdir(buildDir.toString() + "/parentFolder")
  for (int x=0; x<=100; x++)
  {
     File currentFile = file(parentFolder.toString() + "/file" + String.valueOf(x))
     currentFile.write(String.valueOf(Math.random()))
  }
}
```

### Stage Two

Next, let's say I need to read each file generated in the generateNumberFiles task and zip each file into a separate archive in a second folder, zipFolder.  I'll put it under the parentFolder for simplicity, but the location isn't important.

Desired output:

```
parentFolder
|
|-file1
|-file2
...
|-file100
|-zipFolder
  |
  |-file1.zip
  |-file2.zip
  ...
  |-file100.zip
```

This seems problematic because, in theory, it's like I need to create a Zip task for each file (to generate a separate archive per file).  So I suppose this is the first part of the question: how do I create a separate task to act on a bunch of files generated during a prior task and have that task run as part of the build process?

Adding the task at execution time is definitely possible, but getting the tasks to run seems more problematic.  I have read that using .execute() is inadvisable and technically it is an internal method.

I also had the thought to add `dependsOn` to a subsequent task with a `.matching { Task task -> task.name.startsWith("blah")}` block.  This seems like it won't work though, because task dependency is resolved [during the Gradle configuration phase][1]. So how can I create tasks to operate on these files since they didn't exist at configuration time?

### Stage Three

Finally, let's complicate it a little more and say I need to perform some other custom action on the ZIP archives generated in Stage Two, something not built in to Gradle.  I can't think of a realistic example, so let's just say I have to read the first byte of each ZIP and upload it to some server -- something that involves operating on each ZIP independently.

Stage Three is somewhat just a continuation of my question in Stage Two.  I feel like the Gradle-y way to do this kind of thing would be to create tasks that perform a unit of work on each file and use some dependency to cause those tasks to execute.  However, if the tasks don't exist when the dependency graph is built, how do I accomplish this sort of thing?  On the other hand, am I totally off and is there some other way to do this sort of thing?

[1]: "Gradle builds the complete dependency graph before any task is executed." http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create tasks during the execution phase. As you have probably figured out, since Gradle constructs that task execution graph during the configuration phase, you cannot add tasks later.

If you are simply trying to consume the output of one task as the input of another then that becomes a simple `dependsOn` relationship, just like Ant. I believe where you may be going down the wrong path is by thinking you need to dynamically create a Gradle `Zip` task for every archive you intend to create. In this case, since the number of archives you will be creating is dynamic based on the output of another task (ie. determined during execution) you could simply just create a single task which created all those zip files. Easiest way of accomplishing this would simply to use Ant's zip task via Gradle's [Ant support](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mark, and it's good to hear confirmation regarding the task creation.  As for the use of Ant's zip task, it _seems_ like using Ant tasks was intended more for compatibility with old builds, but I could be wrong.  As this is a new project, I would prefer to keep clean Gradle (without Ant) if I can, and my thought is that Gradle must have some way of handling this scenario.  Maybe Ant is the only way?

Comment: Not necessarily. I don't see another way around creating multiple archives with a single task aside from writing a custom task, which depending on your use case, might be appropriate. In reality, under the hood the Gradle `Zip` task is using Ant so they should be functionally the same. The advantage of using the Gradle task is the conciseness of the Gradle DSL and better incremental build support.

Comment: If I write a custom task, which I have already done for some custom processing, can I harness the built-in task actions of Gradle, such as Zip, Upload, War, etc.?  Or do I need to basically rewrite those actions within my custom task?  I definitely get your point on the incremental build support as I was looking forward to that ability and I'm not sure if/how I could use that in these dynamic scenarios.

Comment: You could extend the `Zip` task, but again, that is designed to create a single archive. You could additionally use the Gradle internal `ZipCopyAction` but this is an internal API and probably shouldn't be used. You could also alternatively use a Java library such as commons-io. I'd personally go with the Ant option. It is a public API, is bundled with Gradle, and provides the functionality you want. You could still write you custom task, the implementation (ie. `@TaskAction`) would simply delegate to Ant.

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar. While Mark Vieira's answer is correct, there may be a way to adjust things on both ends a bit. Specifically:

1. You could discover, as we do, all the zip files you need to create during the configuration phase. This will allow you to create any number of zip tasks, name them appropriately and relate them correctly. This will also allow you to individually build them as needed and take advantage of the incremental build support with up-to-date checks.
2. *If* you have something you need to do before you can discover what you need for (1) and *if* that is relatively simple, you could code that specifically not as a task but as a configuration step.

Note that "Gradle-y" way is flexible but don't do this just because you may feel this is "Gradle-y". Do what is right. You need individual tasks if you want to be able to invoke and relate them individually, perhaps optimize build performance by skipping up-to-date ones. If this is not what you care about, don't worry about making each file into its own task.